# uploading data from localstorage to google drive in a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-drive-api

Integrating a chrome extension(not hosted) with google drive seems to be not possible if I am correct. Is there a way to upload content from 'localstorage to google drive in a chrome extension?

Can the depreciated documents list api be used to do that? if yes, how?

For example, user has some data in the localstorage of the popup.html page in the extension. User would want to backup that data in his google drive. How can it be done from a chrome extension with no hosted page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2):

You can upload files to Drive using JavaScript. Check the step-by-step quickstart [guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-js) for JavaScript to learn about it, you will have to change the code in order for it to read from localstorage instead of the filesystem:

Comment: Thanks Claudio, but what should be the JavaScript origin? as being an extension its not hosted on a webserver.

Comment: The step by step quick start guide doesn't apply to chrome extension whose origin is extension://